# DryIoc Call async initialization method before instance resolve

Tags: c#, initialization, dryioc

I have a class A. It must be a `singleton` and the `async Initialization` method must be called when it is created. I did not find suitable functionality in the `DryIoc` documentation. It seems to me that the `RegisterDelegate` method is the closest, but it does not take an asynchronous lambda as a parameter.

For clarity, I will give an example to be in front of your eyes:

```
public class A
{
    ...
    public async Task<A> Initialization() {...}
    ...
}

var instance = await new A().Initialization();
```

Comment: I have provided a couple of alternatives in my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a quick response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer 1

The `async` initialization is not yet supported by the DryIoc because of the [two-colored function problem](https://www.tedinski.com/2018/11/13/function-coloring.html) and the associated complexity.

Basically, I need to introduce the separate `await` call graph generated for the whole chain of dependencies where some of them are `async` starting from the `ResolveAsync` or similar API.

In the absence of it, you may use the approach discussed at the end of the article https://endjin.com/blog/2023/01/dotnet-csharp-lazy-async-initialization.

In this approach, you are moving the await part of the initialization outside the construction phase into the method(s).

So you may add the async Initialization as a Func dependency into the constructor:

```cs
public class A
{
    readonly Task _finishInitAsync;
    
    // Actually kicking off the initialization part in the constructor to start the job,
    // but postpone the await of the already finished or in-progress initialization until the first using method.
    // Alternatively, you may use Lazy<Func<A, Task>> parameter instead to postpone the whole initialization until the using method call.
    public A(Func<A, Task> initAsync) => _finishInitAsync = initAsync(this); 
    
    // Making it static to detach from the A and simplify the passing it around
    public static async Task Initialization(A a) {...}
    ...
    public async Task MethodUsingTheInit() 
    {
       await _finishInitAsync();
       // do stuff
    }

}

container.Register<A>();
container.RegisterDelegate<Func<A, Task>>(_ => a => A.Initialization(a));

var a = container.Resolve<A>();
await a.MethodUsingTheInit();
```

### Answer 2

You may go full manual mode, which appears much simpler to me.
Call the `Initialization` manually before the first use.

```cs
// `New` allows to construct the A by injecting its dependencies from the container,
// but without actually registering the A itself.
var a = container.New<A>();

await A.Initialization(a);

// Then register the fully initialized A into container
container.RegisteInstance(a);
```

### Feedback

I am very interested on any ideas for this topic as well as for the alternative solutions.

Comment: The second option looks like the most suitable in the case I described. The problem with the first one is that I can't guarantee the uniqueness of the initialization call from the consuming code.